# Retrieving TFS dialog parameters

Tags: tfs, azure-devops-extensions

TFS 2018u1. I'm putting together an extension with a custom dialog. One can specify in the manifest that the dialog takes query string parameters:

```
"properties": { "uri": "mydlg.html?ID={{ID}}&Name={{Name}}"
```

and then provide the parameter values in the `openDialog()` call by passing the `urlReplacementObject`.

Question: short of parsing the query string in `window.location.search`, is there a good way to retrieve these parameter values from the dialog scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't any other way to achieve this as far as I know.